# Dynamically insert expander in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am quite new to jQuery and are currently despairing of trying to insert a dynamically created expander into a jQuery-Mobile page which looks like the following:

```
<div data-role="page" id="myPage">
  <div data-role="content">
    <div id="myContainer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As the expander should be inserted into "myContainer", I am writing:

```
var expander = $("<div data-role='collapsible' data-collapsed='true'><h3 class='category' /><div class='content' /></div>");
$("#myContainer").append(expander);
expander.find(".category").text(/*Some text*/);
expander.find(".content").text(/*Some text*/);
```

However, only a unthemed and not collapsible div appears in my document.

I guess, I will have to manually toggle the creation of the expander similar to refreshing a listview - I did not find anything about that in the documentation, however.

Unfortunately, neither

```
expander.Refresh();
//nor
expander.Expander();
```

seems to exist.

Many thanks in advance for your responses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is in fact a duplicate happening so often that I created a FAQ about it.

You need to use `.page()` on the topmost element that you add to DOM.

See here for details:
http://jquerymobiledictionary.dyndns.org/faq.html

[edit]

I have also reached the moment when I wanted to use `.page` inside a `page*` event and the solution was rather obvious to me - use a semaphore.

If you don't know how to implement a semaphore, see my dual column plugin code as an example (it's on the same site)

Comment: Well - not quite; see http://forum.jquery.com/topic/possible-infinite-loop-when-adding-dynamic-content

Comment: Not sure if you seen my edit. This comment is here to show up in your notifications ;)

Comment: Thanks - that goes into the same direction as my workaround :-)